# QT which mechanism to update gui from loop

Tags: qt, qthread

I hope I get it explained in an understandable way.

I have a for loop in my main context to send commands to a tcpclient. Each loop step should increase a percentage bar. If I send a signal in the loop the bar is only set to 100% after the loop ends.

This is understandable because the main context is blocked during the loop.

If I outsource the complete loop to a thread and send the signal from there it works fine with the percentage bar. But then I have the problem with the qtcpsocket, which is executed in the wrong thread and doesn't send its signals correctly.

So I thought I only outsource the sending of the signal into a thread and the rest remains in the main context.

Unfortunately this doesn't work either, the signals from the thread are only sent when the loop in main context is finished.

Test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include "TestWorker.h"

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Test(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void doit();

public slots:
    void onIncreaseProgressValue();

};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test(QObject* parent) { }

void Test::doit() {

    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    TestWorker* worker = new TestWorker();

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &TestWorker::doit);
    connect(worker, &TestWorker::increaseProgressValue, this, &Test::onIncreaseProgressValue);

    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        qDebug() << "i: " << i;
        thread->start();
        thread->msleep(50);
        thread->quit();
    }
}

void Test::onIncreaseProgressValue() {
    qDebug() << "TEST increase";
}
```

TestWorker.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class TestWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestWorker(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void doit();

signals:
    void increaseProgressValue();

};
```

TestWorker.cpp

```
#include "TestWorker.h"

TestWorker::TestWorker(QObject* parent) { }

void TestWorker::doit() {
    emit increaseProgressValue();
}
```

Console

```
Der Thread 0x10d4 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  93
Der Thread 0x1250 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  94
Der Thread 0x1478 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  95
Der Thread 0x25d4 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  96
Der Thread 0x1b08 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  97
Der Thread 0x2434 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  98
Der Thread 0xaa0 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
i:  99
Der Thread 0x1f10 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x2448 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
TEST increase
```

I'm probably thinking wrong and/or doing something else wrong with the thread. The only thing I have found so far is QApplication::processEvents do force a gui update from main context, but that is apparently not supposed to be used and contradicts the signal / slot approach of qt.

Comment: You state that
"If I send a signal in the loop the bar is only set to 100% after the loop ends.
This is understandable because the main context is blocked during the loop.",
but that sounds strange. According to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) signals trigger the connected slots immediately. Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `Test` lives in gui (main) thread (to verify that add `qDebug() << this->thread();` inside `Test::doit`), so its slots get executed in main thread, so any signals received while `Test::doit` is running will wait in queue until `Test::doit` exits.